# java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out, CRM on Demand Query operation

Tags: java, crm, dynamics-crm-online

Hi Guys please help me this issue,

When I Perform Oracle CRM On Demand operation (Query Integration Queue) Some times i am getting this exception ......

```
java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(SSLSocketImpl.java:625)
    at sun.security.ssl.BaseSSLSocketImpl.connect(BaseSSLSocketImpl.java:160)
    at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:180)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:432)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:527)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.<init>(HttpsClient.java:275)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.New(HttpsClient.java:371)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:191)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:933)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:177)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1092)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:250)
    at com.crmit.ws2.crmoperations.CRMServices.queryEvent(CRMServices.java:2449)
    at com.interfaceglobal.ieqframework.bo.BoIEQSync.queryIQReocrds(BoIEQSync.java:54)
    at com.interfaceglobal.ieqframework.bo.BoIEQSync.queryIQAndSaveInDatabase(BoIEQSync.java:100)
    at com.interfaceglobal.ieqframework.service.StartReadingIQFromCRMOD.main(StartReadingIQFromCRMOD.java:41)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can adjust the connection timeout before getting the Outputstream.

```
urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(<Number of Milliseconds>);
```

Comment: Still i am getting same issue.Any another solution for that.